# Regex: Not operator with grouped selection

Tags: reactjs, regex

As below pattern `(currentStore.*?\}.*?=.*?useApp)` which search for a pattern like this:

`const {currentStore} = useApp();`

But I need a pattern which search for a content where assignation of `currentStore` is happening like below(`Not(currentStore.*?\}.*?=.*?useApp)`):

`currentStore = await MultiStoreService.getStoreInfoByLocation(zipCode, subdistrict);`

I mean conditions which do not follow above conditions
not getting an option, welcoming suggestion if proper solution is not available.
Even if suggestion over edition original question is also welcome.

Comment: Do you mean that the line `currentStore = await ......` should not be present ABOVE the other line? (regex knows nothing about assigments, it only knows characters).

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply @poul  What I'm searching can go with or without await, but where we are assigning values to currentStore but not consuming it like `const {currentStore} = useApp();` or `currentStore.xyz`

Comment: So you're looking for `currentStore =` NOT followed by another `currentStore` ?

Comment: Your sentences have no structure. You make the simplest problem incomprehensible.

Comment: Do you want to match both `const {currentStore} = useApp();` and `currentStore = await MultiStoreService.getStoreInfoByLocation(zipCode, subdistrict);`?

Comment: *"I mean conditions which do not follow above conditions not getting an option..."* What? 

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). Why would you want to parse JS using regex when JS is not itself a regular language?

Comment: I'm writing a codemod which requires to identify syntex, as it is one time task so I'm not going with syntex detection (SDD/SDT)

Answer (score 1):

To match any line that assigns to `currentStore`:

```
^.*?currentStore\W+=[^;]+;
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/j0A9XU6J7lcEnC).

Answer (score 1):

maybe this will help

```
currentStore = await\s+[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*\.[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*\(.*\);
```